# strange behavior of if/else (Java)

Tags: java

I have a piece of Java code that has a simple if-else block as below

```
    if (null != field1 && null != field2 && field1.equals(field2)) 
    {
            validated = true;

    } else if (null == field1 && null == field2) {
            validated = true;

    } else if ((field1 == null && field2.length() == 0) 
            || (field2 == null && field1.length() == 0)) {      
           validated = true;

    } else if (null != field1 && null != field2 && !field1.equals(field2)) {
            validated = false;
            return validated;
    }
```

Strangeness: When field1 and field2 gets the values as

```
field1 = ""
field2 = null
```

With this combination this should hit the third if block and validated should be set to true. Instead, the last if block is getting executed and validated is getting set to false.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Is `field2` the _string_ `"null"`?

Comment: Please fix your second snippet, it is unclear. Where does it come from ? Is it Java code ? Is it from a text file ?

Comment: fixed the snippet. Sorry for the typo

Comment: Are you sure field1 is empty? (i.e. might it contain whitespace? - in which case you could `.trim()` it first)

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd be more consistent in my `foo == null` v. `null == foo` usage, otherwise it implies there's a reason to do it differently. Also, this is a little hard to read. I'd probably use early returns.

Comment: If you're returning in the last block, then field2 **cannot** be `null`.  Are you using threading by any chance?  Something's up here.  I'm sure you haven't broken *logic*

Comment: @user1356042  does null means empty here?

Comment: My guess: after this code snippet, you have something like `return false;` or `validated = false; return validated;` as a catch-all (otherwise, this code won't compile as not all code paths would result in a `return` statement!). That code is being hit, because your third block doesn't have a `return validated` statement. So your third block _is_ being hit, but right after that the "catch-all" happens and you return that default `false`.

Comment: @KickButtowski actually I'm parsing an XML using xtreme and populating a POJO object. Whenever the value tag within the XML is empty it inserts null to respective value field within the POJO object

Comment: @user1356042 why do not you use equals() for checking nulls too?

Comment: @KickButtowski, yes that was the problem. null was not the actual null here...it was a string "null"

Comment: @user1356042 so your issue is solved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61856/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-user1356042).

Comment: @user1356042 can you come to chat plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one your comment,I believe null is a String type that you inject into your `XML` file whenever your XML tag is empty. Hence, when you want to compare your filed against the null which is type String, you use `==` which is totally wrong.

**your comment:**

> @KickButtowski actually I'm parsing an XML using xtreme and populating
>   a POJO object. Whenever the value tag within the XML is empty it
>   inserts null to respective value field within the POJO object – 
>   user1356042

You must use `equals()` rather than `==`

why?

`equals()` compare againts the content which what you are looking for

`==` compare the reference if references are looking at the same location

For example :

```
} else if (null == field1 && null == field2) {
```

to

```
} else if ("null".equals(field1) && "null".equals(field2)) {
```

Comment: `null.equals(field1)` doesn't make much sense. If `field1` is null then `null == field1` is fine. Did you mean `"null".equals(field1)`?

Comment: ya i have realized it already i want to ask more question from the op :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you only returning in the fourth block:

```
} else if (null != field1 && null != field2 && !field1.equals(field2)) {
    validated = false;
    return validated;
}
```

Something else is wrong if field1 and field2 are set like this it will only reach the third block. I copy and pasted you code and just removed the return. This returns validated as you would expect:

```
    String field1 = "";
    String field2 = null;
    boolean validated = false;
    if (null != field1 && null != field2 && field1.equals(field2)) {
            validated = true;
    } else if (null == field1 && null == field2) {
            validated = true;
    } else if ((field1 == null && field2.length() == 0) 
            || (field2 == null && field1.length() == 0)) {      
           validated = true;

    } else if (null != field1 && null != field2 && !field1.equals(field2)) {
            validated = false;
    }
    System.out.println(validated);
```